# Why does Oracle still ship Java 8 for the non-developer desktop JRE?

Tags: java, java-8

[image: Java for Windows download]

With the advent of Java 11, the common consumer JRE is 3 whole feature releases behind. Would it not make sense to update by now, or does Oracle just intend for developers to set their source compatibility to Java 8?

Comment: My mildly educated guess is this has to do with Project Jigsaw, the modularity features that landed in Java 9. In my brief experience the separation of some of what were previously available APIs into modules breaks applications that haven't been modularized. Java 8 would be the last conservative choice likely to just be able run applications that state they need Java. With the advent of modularity, it should now be possible for new applications to just ship with the entire runtime they need, and not require the casual end user to install Java.

Comment: The real answer is: ask Oracle.  The most likely explanation is that they want to wait a bit before pushing it to non-developers ... in case there are problems.   Also, a lot of 3rd-party applications are going to need some work to get them to run on Java 11, so pushing Java 11 too hard to non-developers would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 3):

This is because [they're switching to a long-term service (for stability) and non-long-term-service (for new features) model for support timelines](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). Java 8 was the previous LTS version, so for stability reasons, it has been the default version pushed on people and not 9 or 10.

Java 11 is their very latest LTS version, but it just came out. I'm assuming they want to iron out any found bugs before recommending it more generally, but you'd have to ask Oracle to find out for sure.